# Combination of 2 sql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following tables (its simplified) :

```
 CUSTOMERS
 -int id
 -varchar name

 ENVENTS
 -int id
 -int customer_id
 -int duration
```

My problem is , that i want to get sum of durations with same customer_id and then replace customer_id with name from table customers.

So output should be :

```
+--------------+----------------+
| name         | sum(durtaions) |
+--------------+----------------+
| customername |          12313 |
+--------------+----------------+
```

- thats just an example.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Why has this question been voted down? They asked for a hint, not for the work to do done for them. I think the comment by @revoua would have sufficed as it let them have a go at it and *learn*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to join both tables and use `GROUP BY` clause to achieve this:

```sql
SELECT c.name
      ,SUM(e.duration) AS duration
  FROM Customers c 
  JOIN EVENTS e 
    ON c.id = e.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.id
```

#### See [this sample SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bbe5/1)

---

Edit:

Try `LEFT JOIN` to get customers name with duration 0 if they are not in events table

```
SELECT c.name
      ,IFNULL(SUM(e.duration),0) AS duration
  FROM Customers c 
  LEFT JOIN EVENTS e 
    ON c.id = e.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.id
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f5fe/2)

Have a look at [JOINs in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I guess the `ID` is a autoincrement field, so the grouping should be done for the column `customer_id` as suggested in the answer by @Hardik Patel

Comment: c.id = e.customer_id @feela

Comment: @feeela `id=customer_id`

Comment: that work just nice. And it is possible to add something that will also list other customer names with duration 0 if they are not in events table.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```
select c.name,SUM(e.duaration) as duration 
from customer as c 
left join events as e 
    on c.id = e.id 
group by e.customer_id
```